# Visual Studio 2010 does not build new project

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm developing WinForms application using VS2010. I have about 15 projects in the solution. When I'm adding new one (with couple of references to existing projects) and trying to (Re)Build main executable project the VS does not build the newbie!

Any ideas?

Windows 7, 64bit, no VS addons installed, .Net 3.5, plain C#.

**UPD:** In the Build log I see it was built, **but it was not copied to the $OutDir**.

```
    ------ Build started: Project: NewbieProject, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
      NewbieProject -> D:\Projects\MySolution\NewbieProject\bin\Debug\NewbieProjectr.dll
```

**UPD2:** If I reference newbie project from main executable project the copying happens. BUT! This applcation designed to use IoC container. This means no references between main and newbie should exist. How to deal with VS2010 output copying and IoC containers?

**Correct Solution:** Set every ptoject output to the same folder. For example: "../bin/Debug/"

Comment: No errors?  It just skips it all-together?  So no build text shows up in the `Output` window and there's no bin folder?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the newbie project as a reference to the main executable project?  If not the DLL will not be needed by the main executable and will not be copied...

Comment: That fixed the copying problem. BUT! The application is built using IoC design pattern. This means main executable and newbie should not reference each other. They both reference 'the core IoC project' only.

Answer (score 5):

Open menu **Build** > **Configuration Manager** and make sure all build boxes are checked.

[image]

Comment: No problem, I know the feeling ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's selected in your build configuration. If it isn't you should something on the build output stating "1 project(s) ignored" if not more projects.

**Edit**
Does right clicking the Project in the Solution Explorer and then clicking Build or Rebuild work?